# How to add user info when creating a user?

Tags: users

If I create user khadija with username: khadija, how can I populate the fifth field of `/etc/passwd`?

```
mysql:x:27:27:MySQL Server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash
```

I have not found anything under the useradd man page, and cannot access the Internet in this  setup.

Are there any other options apart from editing `/etc/passwd` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `man usermod` it shows the -c option which is used to modify the comment field for an account in `/etc/passwd`.

example:

```
usermod -c "raspberry pi user account" pi
```

To update the comments field for the 'pi' user account.

Comment: Great thanks. I didn't automatically associate 'user's password file comment field' with what I was looking for.

Comment: All good.. Very often it's just a case of getting the terminology right in order to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the field by editing the file, or you can use `usermod -c`, although nowadays it is called the `comment` field in `man 5 passwd`, this was not always the case, it used to be the [GECOS field on UNIX](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/passwd/), although that
name did not reflect the use it had: providing general information.

The proper population is a comma separated list of four (possible empty) strings. You still see this in how some programs create this part of the passwd entry, pre-seeding it with `UserName,,,`.

The first of those fields should contain the full user name (or program name if used for a daemon etc.); the second the physical location; the third (office) telephone; and the fourth home phone (sometimes telex/fax).

Programs like `finger` can be used to display a persons information, including the structured contents of that field. I have actually used that feature (with Yellow Pages to get information available on all workstation), before the advent of LDAP and personal address books.